# Reading from file FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

So I have text file containing:

```
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows###J. K. Rowling###2007
```

And I have to output it to the FreePascal program in the following form

```
J.K.Rowling "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows" 2007 year
```

I know how to read from file but I don't know how to make it like in the previos form

Can someone help me? I would be very thankful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I guess it's your homework. Splits the string into tokens and put tokens which are included in ### into the front. About splitting the string see http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=9789.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TStringList` in freepascal is the same as in Delphi, then this would do the trick:

```
function SortedString( const aString : String) : String;
var
  sList : TStringList;
begin
  Result := '';
  sList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sList.LineBreak := '###';
    sList.Text := aString;
    if (sList.Count = 3) then
    begin
      Result := sList[1] + ' "' + sList[0] + '" ' + sList[2] + ' year';
    end;
  finally
    sList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

Update, as commented by @TLama, freepascal `TStringList` does not have a `LineBreak` property.

Try this instead (using `ReplaceStr` in StrUtils):

```
function SortedString(const aString : String) : String;
var
  sList : TStringList;
begin
  Result := '';
  sList := TStringList.Create;
  try 
    sList.Text := ReplaceStr(aString,'###',#13#10);
    if (sList.Count = 3) then
    begin
      Result := sList[1] + ' "' + sList[0] + '" ' + sList[2] + ' year';
    end;
  finally
    sList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't; I have checked this in FPC 2.6.0 (Lazarus 1.0 RC2), and there's no `LineBreak` property for [`TStringList`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstringlist-1.html) available.