# Reading from text file into list in FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a text file including:

```
John###198cm###90kg###19age
Tom###120cm###34kg###8age
```

And I want to read them from file into two lists in FreePascal.

I have tried to use LoadFromFile function, which should make a line into list, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of your question [`Reading from file FreePascal`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15447535/576719).

Here is an example using `ReplaceStr()` to convert the `###` characters into a CR LF pair.
When assigned to the text property of a new list, it will be splitted into items.

```
Uses
  StrUtils;

procedure HandleText;
var
  i : Integer;
  sSourceList : TStringList;
  sExpandedList : TStringList;
begin
  sSourceList := TStringList.Create;
  sExpandedList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sSourceList.LoadFromFile('MySource.txt');
    for i := 0 to sSourceList.Count-1 do begin      
      sExpandedList.Text := ReplaceStr(sSourceList[i],'###',#13#10);
      // Do something with your lists 
      // sExpandedList[0] = 'John' etc ...
    end;
  finally
    sSourceList.Free;
    sExpandedList.Free;
  end;
end;
```